# HERE map API doesn't display map - photos inside this post

Tags: javascript, laravel, here-api

I'm following the QuickStart guide https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/quick-start.html

I've followed these steps and can't seem to get the map to render on screen. I'm hoping if I attach my code some generous users may be able to help me solve this issue.

This is what i have tried:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/quick-start.html

I'm using my head.blade.php file to include

```
{{--HERE Map API--}}
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"
            type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"
            type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

into my layout file. Inside of my layout file i have

```
@include('layouts.partials.head')
```

My view contains my map div

```
<div class="col-md-4 rounded text-center boxshadow-secondary" style="padding-left:0;">

                            <div id="mapContainer" style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:9%; margin-bottom:15px;" class="bg-img-person">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

and the here-api QuickStart script at the bottom

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Initialize the platform object:
            // Initialize the platform object:
            var platform = new H.service.Platform({
                'app_id': 'jAvuLRw10MOB9UTKFID6',
                'app_code': 'KaM79eIV6ruGW5KUSWrhaA'
            });

            // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
            var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

            // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
            var map = new H.Map(
                document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
                maptypes.normal.map,
                {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
                });
        });
    </script>
```

My  does include csrf token

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: Where is the result? What exactly is your issue?

Comment: I solved this. I needed to include the style width and height in the div. I can't find the Delete button for my question =/ But the issue was that the map wasn't displaying on the screen. No errors, view loaded fine... just the div didn't show the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include style in your div tag.

```
<div style="width: 640px; height: 480px" id="mapContainer"></div>
```

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/get-started.html